# Default template arguments for function templates syntax

Tags: c++, templates

Are there any differences between

```
template <typename ForwardIter, 
    typename Comp = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIter>::value_type>>
void select_sort(ForwardIter first, ForwardIter last, Comp comp = Comp())
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
    {
        auto iter = std::min_element(first, last, comp);
        std::swap(*first, *iter);
    }
}
```

and the simpler version

```
template <typename ForwardIter, 
    typename Comp = std::less<>>
void select_sort(ForwardIter first, ForwardIter last, Comp comp = Comp())
{
    // Same as above
}
```

Both seem to work. Is it just a style issue? Or are the cases where one have to choose one or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both will work but they are different.

`std::less<T>` is the most commonly use case. It's a class that have the `operator()` overloaded. It is implemented in a similar way as this.

I omitted some special cases about pointers here, but it's only a naive implementation for the sake of simplicity.

```
template<typename T>
struct less {
    constexpr bool operator()(const T &lhs, const T &rhs) const {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
};
```

It's like a functor, but you choose which `T` it will be. The advantage of this solution is that one can specialize `std::less<T>` for special cases of one's code.

`std::less<>` is different. It can compare object of any types, as long as the two types has `operator<` overloaded. It act just like a generic lambda. It is implemented a bit like this:

```
template<>
struct less<void> {
    template<typename T, typename U>
    constexpr auto operator()(T&& lhs, U&& rhs) const
            -> decltype(std::declval<T>() < std::declval<U>()) {
        return std::forward<T>(lhs) < std::forward<U>(rhs);
    }
};
```

As you can see, when you use `std::less<>{}(a, b)`, it's really close to the same thing as if you wrote `a < b`, and will work even with types that has a non-const `operator<`. So this one is the best, as long as the classes you use have the `operator<` overloaded.

Comment: For completeness: the special exception that `std::less<T *>()` is even allowed for pointers that don't point into the same array (unlike `<`) also extends to `std::less<>()`. The definition you put in this answer wouldn't handle that properly. (I do realise you wrote "a bit like".)

Answer (score 2):

`typename Comp = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIter>::value_type>` means that when `Comp` is not specified, `std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIter>::value_type>` is used.

`typename Comp = std::less<>` means that when `Comp` is not specified, `std::less<>` is used.

That's the exact difference. It doesn't mean that the compiler somehow deduces the template argument for `std::less<>`. Instead, since the template `std::less<T=void>` specifies a default value, that default value is used.

The template specialisation `std::less<void>` is defined in such a way that it can generally be used in place of other `std::less<T>` versions. They're not exactly the same thing, there are cases where you'd use one or the other. From your question title though, your question appears to be about the syntax of the default argument, not about `std::less` specifically, so I'll skip the explanation of that.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the first snippet is not valid until C++14

Comment: @EdgarRokyan Which is the current version of C++, so assumed unless otherwise specified. (I think you mean "second snippet", by the way.)

Comment: Yes, definitely. Seems that I lost a concentration to the end of the day :)